# Tutorial / understanding on OpenSSO/AM & Fedlet

Tags: java, opensso, openam

Is there a good tutorial (besides the Oracle ones) easy to follow on how to integrate OpenSSO/AM fedlet and stuff into a servlet (no jsp, just plain servlet stuff)? I can't figure to really find an easy step-by-step one :(

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An OpenAM example exists within the official ForgeRock documentation [here](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/12.0.0/dev-guide#chap-fedlet-java).

It contains JSP but is simple enough to read as a servlet by only focusing on the content inside the <% %> tags.